# How to Decide on a Good Title for a New Job?

Tags: title

I’m currently working as a “Software Engineering Team Lead” and have been offered a new position with a different company and was given the luxury (?) to choose my own title (within reason).

While I think titles really shouldn’t matter, in reality, I think they do quite a lot for compensation, etc.

The role will essentially be an individual contributor position (as opposed to management position previously), coding 50% (writing basic platform code) and coordinating with Partners 30% and driving overall Product strategy 20% of my time.

How do I decide for a good title that doesn’t look like a demotion (going from management to individual contributor) and shows that this position comes with strategic responsibilities as well and will help me in future career steps?

Comment: 'Digital Ninja' has a nice ring to it

Comment: Can you clarify your question? According to google, "IC" is an Integrated Circuit. In terms of job titles, "Ic" is the officer in charge of enemy intel where I live. Please make sure your abbreviations are understood be all.

Comment: Welcome new user.  Please don't use abbreviations like "IC".  You may wish to click edit and write it out clearly, thanks.

Comment: Those downvotes hurt ;-) I'm still learning!

Comment: Staff Engineer.

Comment: ..how about _JACM_ ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't take this the wrong way, but based on what you've told us, it sounds like it *is* a demotion of sorts (at least if you consider management a promotion over engineering). While there is [evidence](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/eye-tracking-study-among-recruiters-how-pass-initial-resume-eekman) that recruiters mostly scan titles during the initial screen, merely coming up with a clever title won't fully prevent that appearance because eventually they'll read the description of what you actually did and ask you to explain it in a phone screening.

If it isn't a demotion, think about why it isn't. Is there some kind of responsibility that you weren't doing before that makes giving up the management portion worthwhile from a career development perspective? Why did you make the move in the first place?

That being said, pick a title that concisely and accurately represents what you're actually doing to someone outside the organization. Don't focus on making it look like it isn't a demotion - you're doing something different.

You could also use a slash (as in, "Senior Software Engineer/Business Analyst") or something to that effect.

Alternatively, if you're having a lot more input in the direction of the product than before (especially relative to other people on the team), a title like "Software Architect" could be appropriate (but make sure that your responsibilities would support the title; as I mentioned before, remember that you'll eventually have to explain what you did in the job in an interview regardless of what title you come up with).

Answer (score 0):

Titles serve two functions:

1. They explain to people *outside your organization* what you do and where you fit in your organization.  That's why "Senior Software Engineering Team Lead" is a good title - people outside the company will recognize it and have a fairly good idea of your role & responsibilities
2. They help HR figure out what pay bucket to put you in.  HR's going to take your title and attempt to match it to salary surveys (again, titles outside your organization) to figure this out.  They'll also look at your boss's title for context and probably limit your choices to a small list they're comfortable with.

Remember that a fancy title doesn't mean a thing when you're shopping for groceries.